# Meaning of "Disease progression was not judged only from changes in the serum CA-125 level"

Tags: sentence-meaning

Quote from a [clinical trial report](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10147-018-1319-y):

> The tumor response and disease progression were evaluated by computed tomography (CT) or magnetic resonance imaging (MRI) according to the new Response Evaluation Criteria in Solid Tumours (revised RECIST guideline, version 1.1) [10] by each investigator. Disease progression **was not judged only from** changes in the serum CA-125 level.

Do they mean "We **did not use** serum CA-125 levels **at all** in our estimation of disease progression"?

The sentence looks ambiguous to me. Maybe they mean that "our estimation was not solely based on CA-125 levels" - but I see no other mention of CA-125 in the paper..

Comment: I think it means *Disease progression was judged not only from changes in the serum CA-125 level, but also some other factors.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the CA-125 levels are only one of the tests/factors/criteria that they used to examine disease progression.

The author/s of the paper might assume that the reader is a scientist of the same field and so has basic knowledge of terms regarding ovarian cancer.

CA-125 test is used to determine whether a woman may have ovarian cancer. From that explanation, it sounds like CA-125 is a basic thing that researchers who deal with ovarian cancer know about.

CA-125 means cancer antigen 125 and is a protein. Having high CA 125 levels doesn't automatically mean that one has ovarian cancer, but it increases the probability until it is properly checked. I'm guessing this was why they said that CA 125 levels aren't their only judging factor.